# ждать, пока придёт ответ js

Tags: javascript, события

```
function update() {
    fetch('/something.json').then(response => {
        response.json().then(source => {
            console.log(source);
        });
    });
}

const id_update = document.getElementById('update');
id_update.addEventListener('click', () => update());

<a href="#" id="update">
    update
</a>
```

при клике вызывается функция, которая возвращает json. если кликов будет много, то сервер будет нагружаться

есть какой-то стандартный метод, который позволит игнорировать клик, пока не придёт ответ

можно, конечно, сделать костыль, но это костыль.

Comment: из очевидного - поставить переменную-замок, по клику закрывать, после ответа открывать. если замок открыт - отправлять запрос.

Comment: @yolosora так и сделал, но это костыль

Comment: throttle & debounce. Хотя, ответ ждать тоже можно - аналогично.

Comment: @ast почему костыль?

Comment: Никакой это не костыль.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

создаете переменную, например

```
var isLoading = false
```

Переделываете свою функцию:

```
function update() {
    if (isLoading) {
        return;
    }
    isLoading = true
    fetch('/something.json').then(response => {
        response.json().then(source => {
            isLoading = false;
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Нормальный ответ же - оставь.

Comment: @Qwertiy окей:) воспользуюсь советом:)

Comment: других решений нет?

Comment: @ast какую вы цель преследуете?:) заблокировать лишние клики на кнопку? уменьшить нагрузку на сервер? Не очень понимаю почему вы считаете что использование дополнительной переменной это костыль:)

Comment: меня устраивает такой вариант, но мне бы хотелось узнать, есть ли какие-то стандартные решения в js или нету.

Comment: @ast, это стандартное решение, во всех смыслах (оно общепринято; логично; и не противоречит стандарту ES).

Comment: Разве что еще на ошибку надо сделать `isLoading = false;`